# Run a script in multiple PostgreSQL databases

Tags: sql, macos, postgresql-9.1, multiple-databases

How can you run a script in multiple PostgreSQL databases in Mac?

Answer (score 4):

```
for db in first_db second_db ...; do
    psql -d $db -f yourscript.sql
done
```

Of course there will be many variations depending on exactly what you want to do.